# Find out how many texttospeech 'items' are processed in the queue

Tags: java, android-studio, text-to-speech

I hope I can make myself clear here.
I have an arraylist with text which I want to read out loud. When, for instance, with 75 objects in the list, after the third sentence spoken, I want to click 'STOP' and do something with the third position of the arraylist I can't find a way to find out the texttospeech queue has processed 3 lines of the queue?

```
if(!sh.Contents.isEmpty()) {
   for (String object: sh.Contents) {
       sh.CurChapter += 1;
       speech(String.valueOf(sh.CurChapter) + " " + object);
       //textToSpeech.speak(substr, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, null)
   }
} else {
       speech( "Section not found!");
}
```

Kind regards,

Mike

Comment: Set your `UtteranceId` to the position of the Array

Comment: Thnx for the tip Brandall. Guess I can use something like a UtteranceProgressListener()  to determine the queue status..

Comment: Yes, I've added an answer to demonstrate

Comment: Thank you Brandall!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your speech array loop, use the position as the utteranceId and set it:

```
speak(utterances.get(i), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, yourBundle, String.valueOf(i))
```

Then in your `UtteranceProgressListener`

```
public static final int DO_ACTION_1 = 0;
public static final int DO_ACTION_5 = 4;

    @Override
    public void onDone(final String utteranceId) {

            switch (Integer.valueOf(utteranceId)) {

                case DO_ACTION_1:
                    // do something
                    break;
                case DO_ACTION_5:
                    // do something else
                    break;
                default:
                    // do nothing
                    break;
            }
    }
```